# Mount SMB / AFP 13.10

Tags: mount, 13.10, samba, fstab, file-sharing

I cannot seem to get Ubuntu to mount a mac share via SMB or AFP. I've tried the following...

AFP:

```
apt-get install afpfs-ng-utils
mount_afp afp://user:password@localip/share /mnt/share
```

Error given: "Could not connect, never got a reponse to getstatus, Connection timed out". Which is odd as I can access the share just fine via Mac.

SMB:

```
apt-get install cifs-utils
nano /etc/fstab
added the following line "//localip/share /mnt/share cifs username=user,password=pass,iocharset=utf8,sec=nltm 0 0"
mount -a
```

Error given:

```
root@Asrock:~# mount -a -vvv
mount: fstab path: "/etc/fstab"
mount: mtab path:  "/etc/mtab"
mount: lock path:  "/etc/mtab~"
mount: temp path:  "/etc/mtab.tmp"
mount: UID:        0
mount: eUID:       0
mount: spec:  "//10.0.1.3/NAS"
mount: node:  "/mnt/NAS"
mount: types: "cifs"
mount: opts:  "username=user,password=pass,iocharset=utf8,sec=nltm"
mount: external mount: argv[0] = "/sbin/mount.cifs"
mount: external mount: argv[1] = "//10.0.1.3/NAS"
mount: external mount: argv[2] = "/mnt/NAS"
mount: external mount: argv[3] = "-v"
mount: external mount: argv[4] = "-o"
mount: external mount: argv[5] = "rw,username=user,password=pass,iocharset=utf8,sec=nltm"
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=10.0.1.3,unc=\\10.0.1.3\NAS,iocharset=utf8,sec=nltm,user=user,pass=*
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I don't really care which it uses I just want it to work! Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: thanks a lot! was searching for this all day. It works on Ubuntu 14 like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

for me it worked without `sec=nltmssp`:

```
//localip/share /mnt/share cifs username=user,password=xxx,nounix 0 0
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get this to work with an fstab of

```
//localip/share /mnt/share cifs username=user,nounix,sec=nltmssp 0 0
```